# Order by Gremlin (on AWS Neptune) descending puts 0 at the top

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a Neptune Gremlin query that should order vertices by the number of times they've been saved by other users in descending order. It works perfectly for vertices where the property value is > 0, but for some reason puts the vertices where the property is equal to zero at the top.

When adding the vertex, the property is created without quotes (so not a string), and I am able to sum on the property when I increment it in other scenarios, so they should all be numbers. When ordering in ascending order it works as expected too (zero values come up first and then ordering is correct).

Has anyone seen this before or knows why it might be happening? I don't want to have to pre-filter out zero values.

The relevant part of my query is the following (and acts the same way with incorrect ordering, but has some stuff in the results that isn't relevant for this question), but I have attached an image for the full query I'm using with the results it gives `g.V().hasLabel('trip').order().by('numSaves', desc)`

[Query and results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwiYs.png)

Comment: Hi - I have not been able to reproduce what you are seeing. In my tests I always get the correct ordering. Is there any more to your full query? It got cropped off in the screen shot. Would you be able to provide a few addV and addE steps that build a sample graph that would allow testing with the exact data model you have?

Comment: The full query is just `g.V().hasLabel('trip').has('published', true).where(out("hasDay").count().is(gt(0))).order().by('numSaves', desc).valueMap().select("location", "numSaves")`

Comment: And I'm building the vertex like this `g.addV("trip").property("location", "Nashville").property("numSaves", 0)` and then later incrementing values like this `g.V("<the trip ID>").property(single, "numSaves", union(values("numSaves"), constant(1)).sum())`

Comment: Hi again - I created a test graph using the steps you provided and I am still unable to reproduce what you are seeing. I get the expected ordering with all the zero value ones coming last. I'm not aware of any issue in prior versions of the engine but could you please share the engine version you are using (from `%status`). I tested using `'dbEngineVersion': '1.0.4.2.R2'`

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'm using 'dbEngineVersion': '1.0.4.1.R4', and 'gremlin': {'version': 'tinkerpop-3.4.8'}. 
I noticed it worked fine when I create vertices like this `g.addV("random").property("location", "test1").property("numSaves",0)` and `g.addV("random").property("location", "test2").property("numSaves",10)`. But when I create them all set to zero and then increment via this step: `g.V("<id of one vertex>").property(single, "numSaves", union(values("numSaves"), constant(1)).sum())` it throws them out of order with those never incremented. Am I accidentally changing the type?

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I'll do some more experimenting based on that.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I am also running into this issue. Ordering by `desc` sorts 0 (zero) at the top, followed by the largest numbers. DB engine version `1.0.4.1.R4`. I have a working reproduction in my AWS account that I am happy to share with you. I am very interested in a solution to this.

Comment: @Will I found a way to workaround this. Try `g.V().hasLabel('trip').fold().unfold().order().by('numSaves', desc)`. Not perfect but it does the sort correctly.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the set of Gremlin steps that creates the data and also the query where the sort order appears incorrect? I was never able to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence In my case I'm counting likes (edge) on posts (vertex). Each like edge has a `likeCount` property which I `sum`. I do all this in a `property` step: `.property( single, "likeCount",  __.inE("like").has("isActive", true).values("likeCount").fold().coalesce(__.unfold().sum(), __.constant(0)))` That value is what I eventually sort on in another process. From what I can tell it is just a regular number value. I've even tried manually setting that property to 0 with the same result `property(single, "likeCount", 0)`

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Also please see my earlier note to @Will about how `fold().unfold()` will cause it to sort correctly.

Comment: Hi @Fook - are you able to open an AWS support case? That would be the best way to pursue this I think.

Comment: I also think I can reproduce this now using the latest information you each provided. Digging a little deeper.

Comment: @Fook and Will. I updated the answer. A Neptune release was just made that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the issue thanks to the very helpful additional information. In the near term, the workaround of using `fold().unfold()` will work as it causes a different code path through the query engine to be taken. I will update this answer when more information is available. The issue seems to be related to the `sum` step. Another workaround that worked for me is to use a `sack` to do the "add one". Not a very elegant query but it does seem to avoid the `order` problem.

```
g.V("some-id").
  property(single, "numSaves",             
           sack(assign).by('numSaves').
           sack(sum).by(constant(1)).sack())
```

UPDATED July 29th 2021:

An Amazon Neptune update (1.0.5.0) was just released that contains a fix for this issue.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin and Fook! Those solutions worked!

Comment: I can confirm this Neptune update fixes my issue.